# facing problem while displaying the value of the variable

Tags: android, uitextview, runtime-error

I have just tried to display the value of the variable but is showing some kind of exception
that is FORCE CLOSE.

the code i have tried is

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result9);
myTextView.setText("your score is " +count);
```

considered count=0 intially.

Can any one suggest me for this problem

thanks in advance

Comment: There are several options, if you post some more code, and the logcat log, we might give you a concrete answer and won't just throw guesses.

Comment: Please show the logcat error.

Comment: Success!
Starting activity option.matrix.Act on device emulator-5554
 ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=option.matrix/.Act }

Comment: This is my logcat. I think there is no problem with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if myTexyView is in dialog you have to do this:
myTextView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById();

anyway do clean project...this happens sometimes:

in eclipse: project->clean->your project

Comment: i have done as you have specified that is clean the project but same problem

Comment: then you have some simply mistake. if findViewById returns null, then its a reference problem. check setContentView,layout name, layout item type, item id...and that spelling stuff, you've typed something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Seems `findViewById()` returns `null`. It means that either there's no widget with id `result9` in current layout or your forgot to `setContentView()`.

Answer (score 1):

can please check your xml which one you have set, setContainView() it mast have TextView with "result9" this id.